# React-Native Redux Create Array in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, redux, react-redux

The main problem is about `react-native redux`/javascript in general.
I want to create a special kind of "Todo-list", which means, that there are parent categories (in this case `PackingLists`) and each of them includes a `name, two dates and the item array`.

That means:
***We assume, that we have a list of "Packinglists" (e.g. Madrid, Paris and Berlin).
It should be possible to add items to each of them (e.g. Madrid contains a Jeans and Shirt and Paris a skirt & a pair of shoes). The idea behind the result should be clear now!***

There is no problem in the creation of the Packinglists. I just don´t know how to "append"/modify the "Packinglist" and add/remove items from the array in each list with react-redux (in PackingListReducer.js - the problem is in `add_ItemToPackingList`) . Can you help me?

index.js (actions)

```
export const addPackingList = (name, startDate, endDate, items) => ({
    type: 'add_PackingList',
    payload: {
      name,
      startDate,
      endDate,
      items
    }
});

export const addItemToPackingList = (parentItem, itemName, isDone) => ({
    type: 'add_ItemToPackingList',
    payload: {
      parentItem,
      itemName,
      isDone,
    }
});


export const removePackingList = (name) => ({
    type: 'remove_PackingList',
    payload: name
});
```

PackingListReducer.js

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'add_PackingList':
        return [...state, action.payload];

      case 'add_ItemToPackingList': {
        const currentList =
          state.filter(packingList => packingList.name === action.payload.parentItem);
          console.log(state);
          console.log(currentList);

        //return { ...state, items: [...currentList, action.payload] };
        return Object.assign(state, { items: [...currentList, action.payload] });
      }
      case 'remove_PackingList':
        return state.filter(packinglist => packinglist.name !== action.payload);
      default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

Here I create the parent "PackingList", which works fine.

```
    <TouchableOpacity
         onPress={() => {
           const exists = this.props.packingList.includes(
             this.props.packingList.find(item => item.name === this.state.text));
              console.log(endDate);
                if (!exists) {
                  this.props.addPackingList(this.state.text, startDate, endDate, []);
                  this.props.navigation.goBack();
                }
              }
            }
        >
              <Text style={styles.buttonStyle}>
                   CREATE NEW LIST!
              </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
```

The creation of the "item", which should be added to the parent packing list.

```
    <TextInput
                style={styles.inputText}
                onSubmitEditing={() => {
                    this.props.addItemToPackingList(this.props.route.params.name,
                      this.state.text, false);
                }}
</TextInput>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**Edited**

```
// PackingListReducer.js
const currentListIndex =
          state.findIndex(packingList => packingList.name === action.payload.parentItem);

let currentList = state[currentListIndex];
currentList = { ...currentList, items: [...currentList.items, action.payload] };

const newState = [...state];
newState[currentListIndex] = currentList;

...
return newState;
```

**Updated**

To delete the same items, reducer case would look like this (given the fact that you send `itemName` to your reducer in a payload):

```
case 'remove_ItemFromPackingList': {
        const currentListIndex =
          state.findIndex(packingList => packingList.name === action.payload.parentItem);

        let currentList = state[currentListIndex];
        currentList = { ...currentList, items: currentList.items.filter(item => item.itemName !== action.payload.itemName) };

        const newState = [...state];
        newState[currentListIndex] = currentList;

        return newState;
    }
```

Comment: *Edited:*
Use `.find` instead of `.filter` because `currentList` ended up being an array of one package list: `[{  currentPackageList }]`

Comment: Fixed that `"TypeError" Invalid attempt to spread non iterable instance` with   return Object.assign(state, { items: `[...[currentList]`, action.payload] });`, but the items always override and won´t be in the packing list array (they create a seperate array)

Comment: No, you cannot use `Object.assign`. It just copies properties from one object to another. And your `state` is an array!

Comment: + every add_ItemToPackingList creates a new Packaging List and doesn´t add the item to the parent list. Using your       `return [...state, { ...currentList, items: [...currentList.items, action.payload] }];`

Comment: `case 'add_ItemToPackingList': {
        const currentList =
            state.find(packingList => packingList.name === action.payload.parentItem);
          console.log(state);
          console.log(currentList);

        //return { ...state, items: [...currentList, action.payload] };
        return [...state, { ...currentList, items: [...currentList.items, action.payload] }];
      }`

Comment: My bad once again, we still need to replace our packingList with the new in our state. Going to update

Comment: 2 small more questions - can you show me how I can delete items & update props like "isDone" then? That would be so great! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I updated the answer for delete items. For "isDone" update, I'm confident you can also do it ;)